# Create circular image using picasso

Tags: android, imageview, transform, picasso

I want load the profilr picture image from web url and from the resourses make it circular using Picasso library. I am doing like,

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.4.0'
}
```

Load Image (`R.drawable.profile_sample`) from resources,

```
Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(R.drawable.profile_sample).placeholder(setCircularImage(R.drawable.profile_sample)).into(imageView_ProfilePic);
```

also from the url like,

```
Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load("http://shidhints.com").placeholder(setCircularImage(R.drawable.profile_sample)).into(imageView_ProfilePic);
```

Also I am using setCircularImage() to make the image from resources to circular shape.

```
private RoundedBitmapDrawable setCircularImage(int id) {
        Resources res = getApplicationContext().getResources();
        Bitmap src = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, id);
        RoundedBitmapDrawable roundedBitmapDrawable = RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.create(res, src);
        roundedBitmapDrawable.setCornerRadius(Math.max(src.getWidth(), src.getHeight()) / 2.0f);
        return roundedBitmapDrawable;
    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30664254/using-picasso-library-with-a-circle-image-view

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26112150/android-create-circular-image-with-picasso

Comment: hey buddy use circular imageview library https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView and load it using picasso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have Created a class `CircleTransform.java` to make the image to circle and modified the code to load image from like,

```
Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(R.drawable.profile_sample).placeholder(setCircularImage(R.drawable.profile_sample)).transform(new CircleTransform()).into(imageView_ProfilePic);
```

also from the url like,

```
Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load("http://shidhints.com").placeholder(setCircularImage(R.drawable.profile_sample)).transform(new CircleTransform()).into(imageView_ProfilePic);
```

**CircleTransform.java**

```
public class CircleTransform  implements Transformation {

    @Override
    public Bitmap transform(Bitmap source) {
        int size = Math.min(source.getWidth(), source.getHeight());

        int x = (source.getWidth() - size) / 2;
        int y = (source.getHeight() - size) / 2;

        Bitmap squaredBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(source, x, y, size, size);
        if (squaredBitmap != source) {
            source.recycle();
        }

        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(size, size, source.getConfig());

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        BitmapShader shader = new BitmapShader(squaredBitmap, BitmapShader.TileMode.CLAMP, BitmapShader.TileMode.CLAMP);
        paint.setShader(shader);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);

        float r = size/2f;
        canvas.drawCircle(r, r, r, paint);

        squaredBitmap.recycle();
        return bitmap;
    }

    @Override
    public String key() {
        return "circle";
    }
}
```