# Parsing Uri with CircleImageView

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

How do I Parse `uri` with `de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView`?

[image: Error.png]

**My code**

```
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

    final Uri uri = data.getData();

    StorageReference path = mStoragereference.child("Photos").child(uri.getLastPathSegment());


    path.putFile(uri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener < UploadTask.TaskSnapshot > () {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

            FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

            UserProfileChangeRequest profileUpdate = new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder()
                .setPhotoUri(Uri.parse(userPhoto))
                .build();

            if (userPhoto == null) {
              Toast.makeText(EditInfo.this, "Error updating image",
                             Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```

Thanks for your response!

Comment: You can try picasso lib. Maybe it will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30664254/using-picasso-library-with-a-circle-image-view

Comment: Do you want to set that `uri` as source for circle image view?

Answer (score 0):

Since [`CircleImageView` is a subclass of `ImageView`](https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView/blob/master/circleimageview/src/main/java/de/hdodenhof/circleimageview/CircleImageView.java#L45) it inherits most of its [properties/methods from `ImageView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html).

Unfortunately it seems that [ImageView doesn't expose its source URI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37013458), so you'll have to keep the URI that you pass into the `CircleImageView` around.